# Cannot start rails server: undefined method `yaml_as' for BigDecimal:Class (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I am upgrading a project from rails 3 to rails 6.0.0.  I have also updated to Ruby 2.6.3.  Upon running `rails s` I encounter:

```
/Users/tibsar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/vendor/builder-2.1.2/builder/xchar.rb:22: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/Users/tibsar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/vendor/builder-2.1.2/builder/xchar.rb:89: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
Traceback (most recent call last):
    21: from /Users/tibsar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
    20: from /Users/tibsar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/bin/rails:23:in `load'
    19: from /Users/tibsar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rails-2.3.2/bin/rails:14:in `<top (required)>'
    18: from /Users/tibsar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    17: from /Users/tibsar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    16: from /Users/tibsar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/rails_generator.rb:28:in `<top (required)>'
    15: from /Users/tibsar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    14: from /Users/tibsar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    13: from /Users/tibsar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support.rb:55:in `<top (required)>'
    12: from /Users/tibsar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    11: from /Users/tibsar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    10: from /Users/tibsar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/core_ext.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
     9: from /Users/tibsar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/core_ext.rb:1:in `each'
     8: from /Users/tibsar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/core_ext.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
     7: from /Users/tibsar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     6: from /Users/tibsar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     5: from /Users/tibsar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/bigdecimal.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
     4: from /Users/tibsar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/bigdecimal.rb:5:in `<class:BigDecimal>'
     3: from /Users/tibsar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/bigdecimal.rb:5:in `include'
     2: from /Users/tibsar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/bigdecimal/conversions.rb:12:in `included'
     1: from /Users/tibsarsoftware/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/bigdecimal/conversions.rb:12:in `class_eval'
/Users/tibsar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/bigdecimal/conversions.rb:16:in `block in included': undefined method `yaml_as' for BigDecimal:Class (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  yaml_tag
```

I've seen suggestions to update the `delayed_job` gem but that has not fixed the issue.

---

*UPDATE*

My Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
# ruby
ruby '2.6.3'

gem "rails", "6.0.0"
```

`bundle install` outputs "Using rails 6.0.0"

However the output of `rails -v` is 2.3.2

Comment: I wonder why the paths in the error message include this segment `rails-2.3.2`? Are you sure that your update to Rails 6.0 was successful?

Comment: @spickermann I've wondered that myself.  In my Gemfile I have `gem "rails", "6.0.0"` and `bundle install` after `bundle update` outputs `Using rails 6.0.0`

Comment: @spickermann I've now discovered that `rails -v` is outputting 2.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to uninstall and reinstall rails manually.

`gem uninstall rails`

`gem install rails -v 6.0.0`

`gem install railties && rbenv rehash`